# Apply pop up to other buttons. Have code that works for one button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that allows me press a button and a pop up appears with the content I want. You can see this below. I want to have multiple of these but am not sure how to change the code. I would like to have different buttons that open different pop up contents.

I've copied and pasted the JS code and changed the relevant IDs but it doesn't work. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!!

```js
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    }

     // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    }
```

```html
HTML (Button):

    <button class="buttin" id="myBtn">Terms & Conditions</button>

HTML (Pop Up Content):

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
     <span class="close">×</span>
      <h3 style="margin-top: 0px;"><strong>Terms and Conditions</strong></h3>
    Please read the following terms and conditions before using our website.
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: use multiple IDs for Multiple POP-UPs AND call them multiple time!!

Comment: Thanks, so in the JS code; would it be like this;

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal'. 'myModal1'); 

and then have the IDs changed in HTML?

Comment: `var modal = document.getElementById('myModal1');`  and use `id="myModal1"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like osyan said in the commen but you vill need a variable pr id. like:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal1');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/3u8ummwn/2/ for a full example

Answer (score 0):

you can do like that: add data-attribute="modalId" to button and on click get that id, and by that id get modal's dom

```js
// Get the modal
    

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function(event) {
    event.target.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none";
    }
    span2.onclick = function(event) {
    event.target.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none";
    }

     // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      
      if(event.target.className=="close")
         return;
      
      var modal = document.getElementById(event.target.getAttribute("data-modal"));
      
         if (event.target != modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
      
        if (event.target.hasAttribute("data-modal")) {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }
      
     
    }
```

```html
HTML (Button):

    <button class="buttin" data-modal="myModal">Terms & Conditions</button>

HTML (Pop Up Content):

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
     <span class="close">×</span>
      <h3 style="margin-top: 0px;"><strong>Terms and Conditions</strong></h3>
    Please read the following terms and conditions before using our website.
    </div>
    </div>

<br/>
 <button class="buttin" data-modal="myModal1">New Button</button>

  <div id="myModal1" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
     <span class="close" >×</span>
      <h3 style="margin-top: 0px;"><strong>Terms and Conditions 11111</strong></h3>
    Please read the following terms and conditions before using our website.
    </div>
    </div>
```